# How long does it take to receive German work permit using a valid contract?

Tags: germany, visa

Given that, I am non-EU citizen, and I already have a valid contract with an employer in Munich or Berlin. Then, i wish to know, ***how long does the process of generation of my work permit takes time?***

A friend of mine said, it depends on your salary. If it is above the BlueCard threshold (for IT jobs in 2018 was €39,624), then the migration office `Ausländeramt` will give you the work permit immediately.

1. Does the length of process depends on salary?
2. Does this policy convince the companies to pay the salary above €39,624, so that the employee can start his work immediately?

Comment: Did you get your B.Sc./M.Sc. in a German university?

Comment: @lawful_neutral no, i got my MSc in Estonia

Comment: Ok, then it's not applicable. I asked because for people with a German diploma there is no salary threshold.

Comment: @lawful_neutral has that changed recently? I have a friend with a MSc from a German uni who had to have the salary requirement for an IT job in Berlin during the time they had the 19a visa. That was four or five years ago.

Comment: You can check at https://anabin.kmk.org/no_cache/filter/hochschulabschluesse.html (in German) if your university and the degree you've got (both together) have been accredited and are valid for the blue card (§ 19a AufenthG). If they are, that speeds things up. If not, you'll have to get your degree accredited, which involves an apostilled translation. The degree needs to be relevant to the concrete job offer you have.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, in 2019 the minimum salary is 41,808 euro (http://www.bamf.de/EN/Infothek/FragenAntworten/BlaueKarteEU/blaue-karte-eu-node.html)

Based on my experience, getting the approval takes at least 2 weeks, and it depends on the city, in big cities employees in the foreigners offices are very busy, so it might take much longer. Some sources (https://www.apply.eu/BlueCard/Germany/Germany.pdf) say that "maximum processing time is three months". Receiving the card itself takes 1 month, but having the approval is enough to be able to work.

AFAIK the time does not depend on your salary, with low salary you just wouldn't be able to get a blue card.

It's hard to answer your second question, I believe it depends on the company. I wouldn't expect a company to raise your salary by a significant amount just to be able to hire you, unless you are a really good specialist, but in this case your salary would exceed 42k euro anyway. For junior positions it's much easier to just hire someone who already has a work permit.

Comment: Producing the physical _Aufenthaltstitel_ document used to take a month. I've heard that from several different _Auslaenderbehoerden_. If OP comes in from a country that requires a visa to enter Germany, they can get a temporary work visa to enter and start working, but need to go to _Auslaenderbehoerde_ immediately and finish the paperwork. That requires a rent contract as well, and some other things. They then start producing the ID card. Once they have that card, they have a 19a with a Schengen visa and their spouse's reunion visa will go through.

Comment: That's correct, blue cards (I mean physical cards) are printed in Berlin, so this time doesn't depend on the ABH.

Comment: they are produced by _Bundesdruckerei_ which is located in Berlin, yes. Just like passports and ID cards. Funny enough, the _Auslaenderbehoerde_ Berlin only gives them out for certain types of visa now. One of my friends went from 19a to _Niederlassungserlaubnis_ in Berlin, and their card was not renewed, but rather taken and they now have a full-page sticker visa in their passport.